# Android HttpTransportSE socket timeout exception and takes too long

Tags: android, sockets, android-ksoap2

I need to call a soap web service using HttpTransportSE, i am using the method below:

```
 HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,40000);
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Eee", e + "");
    }
    //    result = (String) envelope.getResponse();
    String isFaulted="true";
    try {
        SoapObject res = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        SoapObject t = (SoapObject) res.getProperty("MethodResult");
        result = t.getProperty("Result").toString();
        isFaulted =t.getProperty("IsFaulted").toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        SoapFault res = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
        Log.d("Eee", res.getMessage());
    }
```

When i call this method `new HttpTransportSE(URL,40000)` without 40000 it return `sockettimeoutexception`, else when calling it with 40000 seconds it takes about 1 min to return true result

any help how to reduce time without socket timeout exception?

Comment: Please check you namespace, url, method name and soap_action.

Comment: all is okay otherwise the method will return false , it return true with real result when delay is 40000